# Add ko function to global object (using requirejs)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I would like to access a function which is inside a ko viewmodel (as it needs to use its properties) from an outside function. I will have access only to the string name so I came up to add it to the global object.

```
define(['jquery', 'knockout', "/Scripts/AMPUtils.js"], function ($, ko, utils) {

    var init = function (events, forOwnedItemFlag) {
        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(events, forOwnedItemFlag));
    };

    var ViewModel = function (groups, forOwnedItemFlag) {
        ...
        window.delete = function (event) {
            //...code
        });  
        ...
};
```

And then once I pick the name of the function as a string I call it using

```
window[deleteFunctionName]();
```

Is it the only way, is it the right decision?

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling this from a binding (like `click`)? `$root.yourFunction` will give you access to the root view model.

Comment: No. I was using that and it was working but I would like to use it in a script inside the layout. It is for binding a class to open a jquery-ui delete confirmation dialog, picking up the title, the message and in some cases the action to call via html5 data-* (therefore I just have the function as a string)

Comment: Further to my comment I retrieve the name of the function to be called when clicking the delete button of the dialog